# Mule Cloud Hub Deployment Error How can i resolved it?

Tags: salesforce, mule, jira, mule-studio, mule-el

I have done flow Salesforce to JIRA. Its Working fine in Local machine. When i have deployment on cloud hub its not working Its show the error. The following end point URL i am using.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" address="http://00.00.000.000:80/JIRAListner" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

This is not working when i am deploy on cloud hub. How can resolve this problem. After deployment this type of link came. `example.cloudhub.io`. At deployement time which type of endpoint URL i can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint
      exchange-pattern="one-way"
      address="http://localhost:${http.port}/JIRAListner"
      doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Comment: Instead of local host can i use public IP Address?

Comment: http://localhost:${http.port}/JIRAListner this is correct for common port number anyway thanks david

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution when we go to deploy we won't worry about our ip address in mule end point URL.

> `http://127.0.0.1:8081/pathname`

its enough. after deploy the mule project. Deployment give some link like

> `example.cloudhub.in`

. we can use this link with our path name in source application that means where the mule receive the data. example:

> `http://example.cloudhub.in/pathname`

.